# How to encrypt WIndows password in Jenkins and pass it to an Ansible job?

Tags: windows, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins, ansible-vault

I have been trying to run an Ansible job from my Jenkins server onto a Windows host that is connected to a domain.  I have tried the following for authentication.

This first method works, but it has my password saved in plain text and I would like to encrypt it:

```
ansible_user: 'username@domain.com'
ansible_password: 'myplaintextpassword
```

This second method fails and gives me an error.  Basically I was trying to save the windows domain password in the secret text store within Jenkins, and simply passing that into the Ansible job as it's own variable:

```
ansible_user: 'username@domain.com'
ansible_password: '{{ jenkins_secret_text_variable }}'
```

`fatal: [myhost.domain.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host host.domain.com port 22: Connection timed out\r\n", "unreachable": true}`

The third method I've tried is to echo out the jenkins_secret_text_variable into a "vaultpassfile" within Jenkins, and then using the Ansible flag within the Jenkins plugin:

```
--vault-password-file '${WORKSPACE}/vaultpassfile
```

This method fails as well and gives me the exact same error as the second method.  So what is the correct way to encrypt my Windows password within Jenkins, and passing it into my Ansible job?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/), you can specify a credential via it's unique identifier in Jenkins' credential store and then access the username and/or password stored in the credential, like so:

```
def myCredential = 'abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop'

withCredentials([[$class; 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: myCredential, passwordVariable: 'MY_PASS', usernameVariable: 'MY_USER']]) {

    // MY_PASS and MY_USER are now available as environment variables

}
```

Then in your playbook you can reference those variables by looking them up. For example in an group_vars file you could have:

```
windows_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'MY_USER') }}"
windows_pass: "{{ lookup('env', 'MY_PASS') }}"
```